# Error in Android studio while trying to run Miwok app project

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to learn about multi screen app. So I downloaded Miwok app from github and tried to import it to my android studio; but I get the error message:

[image]

The system can't find the file specified. In messages gradle sync of android studio. How to solve this?

Comment: if you are a beginner then my advice would be to start with simple apps or apps which can directly be created using inbuild layout (there are lot) , just get used to android and studio and for this error ,try clean and run

Comment: Please read "[mcve]" and "[ask]".